# jQuery returns NaN

Tags: jquery, nan

I have a problem - when I complete both fields(input 1 and input 2) and I try to change one of them, jQuery returns NaN . Can someone help me, please?

I've tried to use parseInt, parseFloat but it still doesn't work

Sorry for my english:]

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name^="input"]').keypress(function(event) {
        if(event.which && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });


    var $tabs = $('input[name^="tab"]');
    $.each($tabs, function(i, a) { $(a).val(''); });

    $('input[name^="input"]').keyup(function() {
         var count = parseInt($(this).val());

         if($(this).attr('name') == 'input1') {
             var newValue = count * parseFloat($('input[name="tab1_hidden"]').val());
             $('input[name="tab1"]').val(newValue);
        }

         if($(this).attr('name') == 'input2') {
            $.each($tabs, function(i, a) {
                if(i > 0) {
                    var inputHidden = $(a).attr('name') + '_hidden';
                    var newValue = count * parseFloat($('input[name="' + inputHidden + '"]').val());
                    $(a).val(newValue);
                }
            });
         }

    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post"><div>
<p>input 1: <input type="text" name="input1" value=""></p>
<p> <input type="hidden" name="input1_hidden" value=""></p>
<p>input 2: <input type="text" name="input2" value=""></p>
<p> <input type="hidden" name="input2_hidden" value=""></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>tab 1: <input type="text" name="tab1" value=""></p>
<p><input type="hidden" name="tab1_hidden" value="10"></p>

<p>tab 2: <input type="text" name="tab2" value=""></p>
<p> <input type="hidden" name="tab2_hidden" value="20"></p>

<p>tab 3: <input type="text" name="tab3" value=""></p>
<p> <input type="hidden" name="tab3_hidden" value="30"></p>

<p>tab 4: <input type="text" name="tab4" value=""></p>
<p> <input type="hidden" name="tab4_hidden" value="40"></p>

<p>tab 5: <input type="text" name="tab5" value=""></p>
<p> <input type="hidden" name="tab5_hidden" value="50"></p>

<p>tab 6: <input type="text" name="tab6" value=""></p>
<p> <input type="hidden" name="tab6_hidden" value="60"></p>

<p>tab 7: <input type="text" name="tab7" value=""></p>
<p> <input type="hidden" name="tab7_hidden" value="70"></p>

<p>tab 8: <input type="text" name="tab8" value=""></p>
<p> <input type="hidden" name="tab8_hidden" value="80"></p>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: what are the values it is trying to parse? (i.e. what do you have in the input fields)

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your code. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/133242

Comment: Or at least `console.log()` the values you're trying to multiply so you can determine if they actually are what you think they are.

Comment: provide more information about what you really want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:**

js:

```
    count = 0

$("input=[name='input1'], input=[name='input2']").change(function(){
    if ($(this).attr("name") == "input1") {
       count = $("input=[name='tab1_hidden']").val();
       value1 = count * parseInt($(this).val())
       $("input[name='tab1']").val(value1);            
    }

    if ($(this).attr("name") == "input2") {
        value2 = $(this).val();
        countArray = [];

        i = 0

        $(".hidden").each(function() {               
            countArray[i] = $(this).val();               
            i++;
        });

       $("input=[name='tab2']").val(value2 * countArray[0]);
       $("input=[name='tab3']").val(value2 * countArray[1]);
       $("input=[name='tab4']").val(value2 * countArray[2]);
       $("input=[name='tab5']").val(value2 * countArray[3]);
       $("input=[name='tab6']").val(value2 * countArray[4]);
       $("input=[name='tab7']").val(value2 * countArray[5]);
       $("input=[name='tab8']").val(value2 * countArray[6]);

        }
    });        
});
```

html:

```
<form action="" method="post"><div>
<p>input 1: <input type="text" name="input1" value=""></p>
<p> <input type="hidden" name="input1_hidden" value=""></p>
<p>input 2: <input type="text" name="input2" value=""></p>
<p> <input type="hidden" name="input2_hidden" value=""></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>tab 1: <input type="text" name="tab1" value=""></p>
<p><input type="hidden" name="tab1_hidden" value="10"></p>

<p>tab 2: <input type="text" name="tab2" value=""></p>
<p> <input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="tab2_hidden" value="20"></p>

<p>tab 3: <input type="text" name="tab3" value=""></p>
<p> <input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="tab3_hidden" value="30"></p>

<p>tab 4: <input type="text" name="tab4" value=""></p>
<p> <input type="hidden" class="hidden"  name="tab4_hidden" value="40"></p>

<p>tab 5: <input type="text" name="tab5" value=""></p>
<p> <input type="hidden" class="hidden"  name="tab5_hidden" value="50"></p>

<p>tab 6: <input type="text" name="tab6" value=""></p>
<p> <input type="hidden" class="hidden"  name="tab6_hidden" value="60"></p>

<p>tab 7: <input type="text" name="tab7" value=""></p>
<p> <input type="hidden" class="hidden"  name="tab7_hidden" value="70"></p>

<p>tab 8: <input type="text" name="tab8" value=""></p>
<p> <input type="hidden" class="hidden"  name="tab8_hidden" value="80"></p>
</div>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F6Kht/4/

Comment: It works but yours code multiplies value from input2 only by the tab2. It must multipling by every of tab(except tab1)

Comment: you mean `count1 + count2 * (theValue)` ?

Comment: No no, i mean: `input1 * count1` `input2 * count2` `input2 * count3` `input2 * count4` ...

Answer (score 0):

`$('input[name="tab1_hidden"]').val()` is an empty string; if you `parseFloat` it, it's a `NaN`. Do any arithmetic with a `NaN` and it infects everything it touches.

Comment: Ok, so i `parseInt` it and return to a string after i'll use it as value but it still not working

Comment: @MrValider: Sorry, I did not understand this comment. It might help if you explained what the code was trying to do; but basically, you want to check for `NaN` results and provide defaults in case the parse fails. For example: `var a = parseFloat($('#a').val()); if (isNaN(a)) a = 0;` - or, if your default happens to be 0, you can also write `var a = parseFloat($('#a').val()) || 0`.

Comment: The code do this: you type number in input1 and jquery multiply it by the value of tab1_hidden. Then shows the result in tab1.

It do similar think when you complete input2 but juqery must multiply it by each of tabs(tab2,tab3...)